# Spring Data Jpa: How to make my foreign key to another table be unique?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My entity

```
@Entity
public class ValidationStepDraftGroup {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "validationStepDraftGroup_id")
private List<ValidationStep> validationSteps;

// no cascade type, you shouldnt be able to modify a automationInformation by saving a ValidationStepDraftGroup
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name= "automation_information_aId", referencedColumnName= "aId")
private AutomationInformation automationInformation;
```

So this Entity has a uniDirectional one to one Mapping. So ValidationStepDraftGroup has a foreign key to the ID of automationInformation but not the reverse.

Only one ValidationStepDraftGroup should be able to exist for an automationInformation ( there can also be 0). How can I enforce this in JPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's implicit. It's a consequence of using `@OneToOne` for the foreign key to be unique.

Assume it is not, then two child entities would have a relationship with the parent, but this implies `@ManyToOne` relationship - contradiction.

If you want to be more explicit, you can define a field of some basic type (for example `Long`), which would be the parent id and add a flag `unique=true` in `@Column` annotation.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I did a Test where I added a Draft with the Repo, and added another draft with the same automationInformation as before and the count in the database only increased by 1